# Looping sql SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one that contain the messages and the other contain the users.

The messages table contain two ids which are "UserOne" and "UserTwo" Id.

I select the other user Id (not the logged one) and  get the unique Ids only by this code

```
$usersEmails = array();
    $query = "SELECT `UserOne`, `UserTwo` FROM `messages` WHERE (`UserOne`='$id' OR `UserTwo`='$id')";
    if($query_run = mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
        if($num_rows > 0){
            while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
                $userOne = $get['UserOne'];
                $userTwo = $get['UserTwo'];

                if($userOne != $id){
                    array_push($usersEmails, $userOne);
                }else if($userTwo != $id){
                    array_push($usersEmails, $userTwo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $loopStop = count($usersEmails);
```

And here the problem began..

I want to select those unique user Email using them Ids that i inserted in that array called **$usersEmails**

I used this code to show the unique users Email :

```
for($x = $loopStop - 1; $x >= 0; $x--){
$query_two = "SELECT `Email` FROM `signup` WHERE `Id`='$usersEmails[$x]'";
$query_two_run = mysqli_query($connect, $query_two);
$get_two = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_two_run);
$email = $get_two['Email'];
echo "$email";}
```

I know that its not good to loop an sql query statement and its very expensive too so any ideas?

Thanks and happy new year

Comment: You're not making an SQL query in your loop. The `mysqli_query($connect, $query)` statement runs the query. The while loop is just pulling another row from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT s.`Email` FROM `messages` m
inner join `signup` s on s.`Id`= m.`UserOne`
WHERE m.`UserOne`='$id'

union 

SELECT s.`Email` FROM `messages` m WHERE
inner join `signup` s on s.`Id`= m.`UserTwo`
WHERE m.`UserTwo`='$id'
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand what is the 's' and 'm'

Comment: This is the alias for table name. You can write the table name before field name like ` ``signup`.`Email`` `. But this is too long :)

Comment: ah okay :D
You want me to cancel my two queries and use these two queries to get the unique Emails?

Comment: This is not two queries, this is ONE query. And yes, you should use this one query instead of your two.